# Change JTextPane EditorKit

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

How do you change the EditorKit of a JTextPane? I want to change it because I found a better way of setting tab size... but that requires me to set it. I dont want to change it to a EditorPane because my code is built to use the Style feature in it.

Comment: Use `setEditorKit(...)` ???

Comment: @camickr My Eclipse was just bugging with the "final" method that it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Eclipse was just bugging with the "final" method that it is

"final" means you can't "extend" the method.

It doesn't mean you can't "invoke" the method:

```
EditorKit editorKit = new SomeBetterEditorKit();
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
textPane.setEditorKit( editorKit );
```